# Coding Standard Question - defined( or \defined(

Tags: component, development, joomla-coding-standards

A general Joomla! coding question... Checking _JEXEC is defined.

In administrator/components/.../src/everywhere it is

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
use function defined;
```

Whereas in components/.../src/everywhere it's

```
\defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

Is there a specific coding standard that we should use for Joomla! code?

Answer (score 4):

I asked this on the Joomla! internal development chat and was told the second one is the optimised version currently in namespaced files.

Richard, a lead Joomla! developer wrote "Backslash makes it clear it is looked for in the global namespace so less risk for name conflict and also a small optimization".

Benjamin, another lead developer wrote "from 7.0+ it then uses opcodes, which is the optimization, so most likely you should go for it also in non-namespaced files"

Comment: ...I was hoping to coerce Benjamin to engage on this page.  Regardless, thanks for posting it here.